# Incorrect array returned from EF with LazyLoadingEnabled = true via AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework

Briefly, if I set `LazyLoadingEnabled=true` when setting data context in my server code, I am getting strange JSON objects, objects with their only property being $ref instead of real JSON objects when I calling the arrays from javascript via AJAX.

Otherwise (with `LazyLoadingEnabled=false`), all elements are correctly returned. But problem with `LazyLoadingEnabled=false` is that I can't use navigation properties at all in my server code. because I will get an runtime error saying one of navigation properties null.

So my question: Is there any way returning array with correct elements with `LazyLoadingEnabled=true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get  your lazy loaded navigation properties before serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not sure what you are talking about. Serialization is automatically done in web api.

Comment: Of cause. But you need to dispose your dbcontext before it in your controller. Lazy loading is possible only when dbcontext is open, so you need to get navigation proprties before dbcontext is disposed.

Comment: Well...I think I understand what you mean. I can do `LazyLoadingEnabled=true` on demand - whenever necessary as long as dbcontext is accessible. *sigh* ^^ If so, you are right. It's working now. My confusion was my stupid assumption that I have to set lazyloadingenabled in initialization of dbcontext.